# Configure Client Certificates on WCF service in Azure WebApp

Tags: wcf, azure, ssl

I have a WCF service that I want to configure with Transport Security and Client Certificates. I have this working on my local IIS instance, but having troubles configuring it in an Azure Web App.

Here are som snippets from the web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="ApiBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
            <certificate
              findValue="<Thumbprint>"
              storeLocation="CurrentUser"
              storeName="My"
              x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding> 
    <binding name="apiBindingSecure" textEncoding="utf-8">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="ApiService" behaviorConfiguration="ApiBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="apiBindingSecure" contract="IApiService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

When I call the service I get the following error:

> The SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'None'.

I found that in IIS this relates to the SSL Settings -> Client certificates -> Accept setting:[IIS SSL seettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Anj0.png)

However in Azure this has to be done through a web.config setting:

```
<location path="BdoApiService.svc" >
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <access sslFlags="SslRequireCert,SslNegotiateCert" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

I tried different combinations of settings: "Ssl"; "Ssl,SslRequireCert,SslNegotiateCert"; "SslNegotiateCert", etc.

But when I set sslFlags, I always get the following error in the browser:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: Did you find the answer, I am having same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not. We implemented a workaround with secret's trhat are passed in the header. I since then left the project and I'm not sure if they ever got it sorted out...

Comment: Such workaround is what I was afraid of.. thanks @Felix